# How to describe someone with an adjective?

Tags: meaning, phrases, adjectives

I want to say that 'If I should give you an adjective that would be '.
Although I am not sure if this is correct or if there is any better way to say that?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?  I'm not certain what you are asking.

Comment: I vote this the greatest question title anyone has ever posted here.

Comment: You may be looking for "epithet": http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epithet

Comment: @JohnClifford - I vote yours, the greatest comment anyone has ever posted here.

Comment: Aww, shucks. Thanks! Also I think you're right with epithet, and am honestly floored that you managed to figure out what the question was asking.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I want to say that 'If i should describe you with an adjective(or with 1 word) that would be ...' i dont know if you get the meaning. In the first part (if i should) i want to be assumptive

Comment: ***If I were to describe you in a word it would be: earnest***

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand what you were asking now. Yeah, Jim or C. Holt's answers would both be good choices.

Answer (score 5):

You might say, "if I could choose one word to describe you", I would use *beautiful*.

Also common is "[in a word](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+word)", as in "you are – in a word – beautiful."